# Extending javascript object

Tags: javascript

I already have this:

```
var myVar = { appName: 'Test' };
```

I want to add this:

```
myVar = {
         exec: function()
             {
                console.log('do stuff');  
             } 
         }
```

And have this:

```
   myVar = {
               appName: 'Test',
               exec: function()
               {
                 console.log('do stuff');  
               } 
           }
```

Actually, I want to be able to access `myVar.appName` and `myVar.exec();`

So, I can:

```
myVar.exec = function(){};
```

But if I have many more functions and variables.

Do I have to keep doing this:

```
myVar.func1 = function(){ // stuff 1 };
myVar.func2 = function(){ // stuff 2 };
myVar.func3 = function(){ // stuff 3 };
```

Are there a better way?

Comment: You realise javascript objects are essentially just maps that you can add any key/value pair you want to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)!

```
var myVar = { appName: 'Test' };
Object.assign(myVar, {
    exec: function(){
        console.log('do stuff');  
    }
    exec2: function(){
        console.log('do other stuff');  
    }
});
```

You can then access `myVar.appName`, `myVar.exec`, and `myVar.exec2`.

Comment: Yes! That's great! Thank you!

Comment: I'm happy my solution helped! Would you consider marking it as the answer?

Comment: I didn't realize until you mentioned it. I just did. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
myVar.exec = whatever;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
myVar.exec = function(){
    console.log('do stuff');  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var myVar = { appName: 'Test' };
myVar.exec = function() {
    console.log('do stuff');  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set the object equal to a "var":

```
var myVar = {
    appName: 'Test',
    exec: function() {
        console.log('do stuff');  
    } 
}
```